Pause and un paused Python tkinter canvas for loop?
When I click my program's tkinter (canvas) menu it cause pause and when I get rid off the mouse pointer from menu it cause un paused. How to create just this kind of pause in to my program's tkinter canvas in for loop?
I try create menu button 'click' -> pause and other 'click' -> un pause. My code is showing list of images in for loop. I want to add pause in to the loop and then start it again, continue same state as it was before pause.
I've tried sleep and other functions here but, they doesn't work, because I can't use any functions or events during pause. Only after pause I can use other commands and functions.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] showing how you've tried to solve the problem so far. Remember: we can't help you if we can't see what you've tried!

Since you did not provide any code to work with, here is a little sample of how it could be done. Consider the following:

instead of using a binding on a menu I demonstrate the functionality by the press of a button
I used a list of integer strings instead of images to loop through
insted of a for loop I use a sort of recursion utilizing the after mehtod of tkinter. This way the gui stays responsive and other functions can still be called

Here is my code:
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button


class StopLoop(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.img_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4']  # pretend those are your images
        self.counter = 0
        self.looping = False
        # pretend we are displaying images instead of numbers
        self.img_lbl = Label(self, text=self.img_list[self.counter])
        self.img_lbl.pack()
        self.start_stop_btn = Button(self, text='start', command=self.toggle_loop)
        self.start_stop_btn.pack(side='left', pady=5, padx=5)
        # other button to showcase how the GUI is always responsive
        self.other_func_btn = Button(self, text='other func', command=lambda: print('other func'))
        self.other_func_btn.pack(side='right', pady=5, padx=5)
        self.loop()

    def toggle_loop(self):
        """toggle if the loop should pause or continue and change toggle button text respectively"""
        self.looping = not self.looping
        if self.looping:
            self.start_stop_btn.configure(text='stop')
        else:
            self.start_stop_btn.configure(text='start')

    def loop(self):
        """loop continuously via "recursive" .after call but only do actions if self.looping is true"""
        if self.looping:
            self.counter = self.counter + 1 if self.counter < len(self.img_list) - 1 else 0
            self.img_lbl.configure(text=self.img_list[self.counter])
        self.after(1000, self.loop)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = StopLoop()
    app.mainloop()


